# Using Box-Jenkins methodology for intervention analysis

Tags: time-series, arima, intervention-analysis, box-jenkins

I'm trying to follow B-J methodology for my intervention analysis. My understanding of of the first step is that, one should detrend any systematic trends such as seasonality then determine the lag order by observing the PACF and ACF of the detrended series. But I now have to include a dummy variable for the intervention analysis. In which step should I include the dummy variable in the model?